# Instead of looping needs a handy way of setting node list value in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I've the below xml and my needs is to set up the WF_PROCESSID in each of the ROW without looping and setup in c#. Could you please anyone suggest the solution?

```
<RESP_WF_MAP>
 <ROW>
  <PLAN_FOR_RESP>Mombasa</PLAN_FOR_RESP> 
  <WF_PROCESSID>-9999</WF_PROCESSID> 
  <WF_PROCESSNAME /> 
  <DIRECT_MAP_YN>N</DIRECT_MAP_YN> 
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
  <PLAN_FOR_RESP>Mombasa-Changamwe Branch</PLAN_FOR_RESP> 
  <WF_PROCESSID>-9999</WF_PROCESSID> 
  <WF_PROCESSNAME /> 
  <DIRECT_MAP_YN>N</DIRECT_MAP_YN> 
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
  <PLAN_FOR_RESP>Mombasa-Mombasa Branch</PLAN_FOR_RESP> 
  <WF_PROCESSID /> 
  <WF_PROCESSNAME /> 
  <DIRECT_MAP_YN>N</DIRECT_MAP_YN> 
  </ROW>
</RESP_WF_MAP>
```

I want to eliminate this loop and needs a handy xml processing method

```
for ( intIndex = 0 ; intIndex < intLength ; intIndex++ )
{
    xmlRowElement           = (XmlElement)xmlRowNodeList.Item(intIndex);
    strWorkFlowId           = DwXMLUtilBO.getElementTagValue(xmlRowElement,"WF_PROCESSID");  // Customized static method to acquire the element value

    if(strWorkFlowId.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
       DwXMLUtilBO.setElementTagValue(xmlRowElement,"WF_PROCESSID" ,strWfId); // Customized static method to set the element value
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)?

Comment: nope. Can you please suggest solution if you know ?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah the solution is over the link provided by andri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to XML:

```
foreach (var rowElement in XDocument.Load("yourXml").Descendants("ROW"))
{
    var idElement = rowElement.Element("WF_PROCESSID");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idElement.Value))
    {
        idElement.Value = strWfId;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is i don't want the looping. IS it possible without looping ? like xslt processing ?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah: No, XSLT seems more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Try using `XmlDocument` class instead of your custom class, something like this :

```
            var xml = @"
<RESP_WF_MAP>
<ROW>
<PLAN_FOR_RESP>Mombasa</PLAN_FOR_RESP> 
<WF_PROCESSID>-9999</WF_PROCESSID> 
<WF_PROCESSNAME /> 
<DIRECT_MAP_YN>N</DIRECT_MAP_YN> 
</ROW>
<ROW>
<PLAN_FOR_RESP>Mombasa-Changamwe Branch</PLAN_FOR_RESP> 
<WF_PROCESSID>-9999</WF_PROCESSID> 
<WF_PROCESSNAME /> 
<DIRECT_MAP_YN>N</DIRECT_MAP_YN> 
</ROW>
<ROW>
<PLAN_FOR_RESP>Mombasa-Mombasa Branch</PLAN_FOR_RESP> 
<WF_PROCESSID /> 
<WF_PROCESSNAME /> 
<DIRECT_MAP_YN>N</DIRECT_MAP_YN> 
</ROW>
</RESP_WF_MAP>";

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("WF_PROCESSID");

        foreach (XmlNode node in list) 
        {
            node.InnerText = "your new value";
        }

        Console.Write(doc.InnerXml);
        Console.ReadKey();
```